# Arrays: Create Output Table and Provide the Average

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create an array that allows the user to enter no more than 10 pieces of data (in this case number of shirts purchased). The user can enter -1 to finish if < 10 pieces of data or count will terminate at 10. For the output I need to create a Table that shows the user the # in one column and the # shirts purchased in the other, both need a header. I also need the average of the shirts purchased.

If the user enters 0 for shirts purchased I need the system to provide a statement but then continue with the loop.

Below is what I have so far. I am very new to this so any dumb downed explanations would be extremely helpful.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Arrays 

{ 
private static int number;
public static void main(String[] args) 

{
   final int ARRAY_SIZE = 9;
   int[] shirtsPurchased = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
   int count = 0;
   int sum = 0;
   double average = 0;  

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter the number of shirts purchased or -1 to quit: ");
   number = keyboard.nextInt();

   while (number != -1 && count < ARRAY_SIZE)
   {
       shirtsPurchased[count] = number;
       count++;
       System.out.print("Enter the number of shirts purchased or -1 to quit: ");
       number = keyboard.nextInt();
   }

}


}
```

Comment: and what's the problem you facing here ?

Answer (score 0):

You have the lions share of what you need to do already done (I'm not familiar with Java, some syntax errors may be present, but I don't really see any). From what you've described, all I can see that you still have to do are the message if the number of shirts is zero, and the average calculation. While I won't give you the code, I'm sure you can find out how to go about it.

As far as the zero is concerned, you have the input, all you need to do is compare it to zero and output a message if necessary. A simple if statement would take care of that.

To calculate the average, all you'll need is another while loop to sum up all of the numbers of shirts purchased, and divide the result by the number of data elements. Something similar to...

```
while( count is less than number of total shirts ) sum += shirtsPurchased[count];
average = sum / count;
```